# Получить текст из option

Tags: jquery, php, html

Имеется select

```
<select size="1" name="sel">
<option value="0">текст1</option>
<option value="1">текст2</option>
<option value="2">текст3</option>
</select>
```

Как получить из выбранного пункта текст?

```
 echo $_POST['sel'];
```

возвращает значение value, например, 0 или 1.

Comment: @dafa, вам на сервере нужно получить и значения value, и текстовое описание пункта списка? Или только текст?

Comment: Нет, только текст. То что в option: текст1, текст2, текст3.

Comment: Положить в value текст1 текст2 текст3, чтобы в $_POST[] лежало нужное значение?)

Comment: Вот, например, я выбрал пункт 1, где текст "текст1", и после отправки формы получить этот "текст1".

Comment: @dafa, Так почему бы сразу не прописать это в value?

    <select size="1" name="sel">
      <option value="текст1">текст1</option>
      <option value="текст2">текст2</option>
      <option value="текст3">текст3</option>
    </select>

Answer (score 1):

2 варианта:

1) С перезагрузкой страницы:

```
<form action="/php-script.php" method="post">
   <select size="1" name="sel">
         <option value="0">текст1</option>
         <option value="1">текст2</option>
         <option value="2">текст3</option>
   </select>
   <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

2) Без перезагрузки (подключить jQuery):

```
var $obj = $('[name="sel"]');
$obj.change(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: '/php-script.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {'sel':$obj.val()},
        error: function() {
            alert("Internet connection error.");
            return false;
        },
        success: function(response) {
            alert(response);
        }
    });
});
```

В обоих случаях в файле php-script.php получите `$_POST['sel']`

Comment: Спасибо, буду пробовать.

Comment: @Олег Б, но вы же понимаете, что он, @dafa, не про это спрашивал?

Comment: jQuery: $('[name="sel"] option:selected').text();

Answer (score 0):

Лучше делайте это с помощью JS. Почитайте, как это сделать с помощью [selectize.js](https://github.com/brianreavis/selectize.js/). Сам делал это неделю назад, если не разберетесь, кину свой код с комментариями, но мне гуглить долго не пришлось)

Comment: Спасибо, буду пробовать.